# Can't convert from String to Char

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime

I'm trying to Split this string: `2015-08-14 20:30:00`

but the compiler shows this message:

> Can't convert from String to Char

This is my code:

```
string date = reader["date"].ToString().Split("-").ToString();
```

The variable `reader["date"]` is an object, so I must convert it into a String. I want to Split the content into three other variable like this:

```
year: 2015
month: 08
day: 14
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `.Split('-')` (You then call `.ToString()` on an array which is probably not what you want; if you need each element assign to an array)

Comment: Whitch kind of `object` is `reader`? 1) For `DateTime` you should use `.ToShortDateString()` or `.ToShortTimeString()`. 2) for `.Split()`you can not use `.ToString()` it's returns an array of strings.

Comment: There are two mistakes. 1) string.Split does not take string as parameter and 2) It return an array of spitted string. So you have to do like this
var date =  reader["date"].ToString().Split("-");
then you can get the 
year = date[0]; 
month = date[1]; and 
day = date[3].Substring(date.lastIndexOf(" "));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometime a different approach should be considered. If your reader field datatype is date or datetime then using the correct datatype is the correct way to handle this info. A DateTime has already all you need.

```
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["date"]);
int year = dt.Year;
int month = dt.Month;
int day = dt.Day;
```

Answer (score 6):

There is no [`String.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.String.Split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) overload that takes string as a parameter. That's why it looks *closest* overload which is [`char[]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but there is no implicit conversation between them.

```
var array = "2015-08-14 20:30:00".Split(new char[]{'-', ' '});
```

will return

[image]

and you can get them with `array[0]`, `array[1]` and `array[2]`.

Also you can use to parse your string to `DateTime` instead (which your string is valid one) of splitting it like;

```
string s = "2015-08-14 20:30:00";
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    // dt.Year;
    // dt.Month;
    // dy.Day;
}
```

But since these properties are `int`, you will not get leading zeros for your single digit month and days.

In such a case, you can choose to use `dd` and `MM` [custom date and time format specifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

As `String.Split` reaturns an array of strings you need `date` to be the same. So simply write

```
string[] date = Convert.ToString(reader["date"]).Split("-");
```

Comment: actually `Convert.ToString(reader["date"])` if you don't want `NullReferenceException`s.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh Yeap, you´re right, I´ve updated the answer.